# Rename the files by ignoring every thing after first space in file name

Tags: unix, linux

I need to rename all the files in a directory like below:

Original file name: `ABC_DEFGHIJK_LMNO Thu Jul 30 07:29:14 CEST 2020`

Renamed file name: `ABC_DEFGHIJK_LMNO`

So basically I need to ignore every thing after first space while renaming the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a simple bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /path/to/files
for f in *
do
  new_name=$(echo "$f" | cut -d ' ' -f1)
  echo renaming file "$f" to "$new_name"
  # mv "$f" "$new_name"
done
```

If the output is alright, uncomment the `mv` command to rename the files.

Comment: Thanks !!! below command worked at Oracle Linux:for f in *; do  mv "$f" $(echo $f | cut -d ' ' -f1); done

Comment: Oh my god, yes, always quote variables holding filenames with double quotes. Almost forgot in the hurry.